# JSoup HttpStatusException

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to parse the html of the following URL using JSoup:

```
http://brickseek.com/walmart-inventory-checker/
```

When i execute the program I am getting below exception. I am using jsoup-1.10.1.jar

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=http://brickseek.com/walmart-inventory-checker/
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:598)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:548)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:235)
    at Third.main(Third.java:22)
```

Below is the program:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Third {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException {

        String uniqueSku ="44656182";
        String zipCode ="75160";

        Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://brickseek.com/walmart-inventory-checker/")
                .data("store_type","3", "sku", uniqueSku , "zip" , String.valueOf(zipCode) , "sort" , "distance")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2")
                .method(Method.POST)
                .timeout(0)
                .execute();

                String rawHTML = response.body();
                Document parsedDocument = Jsoup.parse(rawHTML); 
                Element bodyElement = parsedDocument.body();
                Elements inStockTableElement = bodyElement.getElementsByTag("table");



    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It works for me. :O

Comment: is it working? Still I am getting the same issue. Can you please tell me in which editor(Ex Eclipse) you are using? Java version and Jsoup version?
I don't know how to resolve this issue :( Will you able to sysout the inStockTableElement  object?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Luna, JDK 1.7.0_67, Jsoup 1.10.1. Yes, I can print the `inStockTableElement` with `System.out.println()` and it prints a `<table>`.

Comment: Still i am getting the same error even using JDK 1.7 and Luna. I have removed all proxy in my system. But no lock :(

Comment: It seems they are doing validation whether we are accessing their URL manually or systematic. Below error message i am getting when i print bodyElement.

 "Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property."  

Don't know how to bypass their validation. It seems they are tracking based on IP address. Please let me know how to bypass their validation

Comment: It's a server validation based on your IP. The only way to bypass it is to use different proxy each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server probably has some sort of method to detect whether you are using a bot to scrape the page. Try changing your http header to something like this:

```
public class Util {
    public static Connection mask(Connection c) {
        return c.header("Host", "brickseek.com")
                .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
//              .header("Content-Length", ""+c.request().requestBody().length())
                .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")
                .header("Origin", "https://brickseek.com/")
                .header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
                .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.48 Safari/537.36")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
                .referrer("http://brickseek.com/walmart-inventory-checker/")
                .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
                .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    }
}
```

This header was copied exactly from the Google Chrome headers - usually, bots are detected by a different order of headers, or by different capitalizations of the headers. By copying Google Chrome exactly, you should be able to bypass it undetected.

Some bot detection algorithms count the number of requests per IP, and starts blocking above a certain threshold - which is why it still works for some people.

Answer (score 2):

Just add ignoreHttpErrors(true) in your code.

```
   Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://brickseek.com/walmart-inventory-checker/")
                .data("store_type","3", "sku", uniqueSku , "zip" , String.valueOf(zipCode) , "sort" , "distance")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2")
                .method(Method.POST)
                .timeout(0).ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                .execute();
```

Thanks